# LuaBridge and Member Functions

Tags: c++, class, lua, member-functions, luabridge

I just downloaded  **LuaBridge** today and am very satisfied with it so far. One thing I've noticed is that I'm able to circumvent the normal requirement of having a lua_State as a function parameter.

I can do this:

```
//C++ files
void love(int i) {std::cout << i;}

luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(lua)
  .addFunction("love", love);

-- Lua file
love(8)
```

and it will work just fine, but if I do anything to the effect of:

```
//C++ files
struct Tester {
  int number;
  void MemFunction (int i) { std::cout << i;}
  static void Register(lua_State*); 
};

void Tester::Register(lua_State *lua) {
  luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(lua)
    .beginClass<Tester>("Tester")
    .addConstructor <void (*) (void)> ()
    .addData("number", &Tester::number)
    .addFunction("MemFunction", &Tester::MemFunction)
 .endClass();
}

--Lua file
  c = Tester()      -- works...
  c.number = 1      -- works...
  c.MemFunction(10) -- nothing!
```

Nothing I've read in the documentation indicates that member functions with non-lua_State arguments can't be registered, and I've seen some LuaBridge code doing just this with no problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the method call syntax

```
c:MemFunction(10)
```

I'd suggest you use the [newer version from github](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge), which has an extensive documentation. It also allows some extra flexibility concerning the input parameters and return values.

Comment: Being a native C++ programmer and writing very little actual Lua code, I have "forgotten the colon" more times than I care to remember. I will add something to the LuaBridge documentation.